# Maven -Using different setting files for different builds

Tags: maven

Is it possible to specify which settings.xml file is to be used while using mvn command?
For 1 project I need to use some settings.xml and for the other different one.

Comment: What kind different settings do you need? Usually you should have only one settings.xml file...

Comment: The question is a bit smelly :), I am pretty sure you want to define different repos or plugins ? Have you considered using [profiles?](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: @javapapo Yes Ined to specify different repos..Is the profiles are the only way to wor with?

Comment: This is the cleanest and most maven-ish way, I would strongly recommend you introduce some profiles. it will make your life a lot easier and for others to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn -s
```

> -s,--settings <arg>                    Alternate path for the user
>                                           settings file